# Javascript - Is this a good practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, standards, document-ready, iife

In our company we're starting a new web project, I'm new in the company, and there are previous apps where document ready is made like this. (BTW we're using jQuery)

```cs
var AccountingMovements = function AccountingMovements() {

    //sometimes they use var _that = this;
    var _this = this;

    _this.Constructor = function Constructor() {
        //here goes the code when document is ready
    }
}

var $AccountingMovements = new AccountingMovements();
$(document).ready($AccountingMovements.Constructor);
```

When I ask my coworkers why they use this pattern, they tell me that Javascript code must have they're own constructor, and that code should be wrriten like this, and when I ask if it's a company rule to do it, they say it is not, there's no company standard that states this should be written like this. It seems they just do it this way because "It's how it has always be done", rather than saying that is a common javascript standarized practice or something similar.

By my side I learned to use IIFE with jquery document ready, which I found in many web examples given by javascript gurus, the actual explanation of use, and even a Wikipedia article. I write my code this way

```js
(function (code) {
    code(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function ($, window, document) {
    $(function () {
        //here goes the code when document is ready
    });
}));
```

My development leader (which doesn't not know too much about javascript, because he comes from a desktop-development background, but he is good when it comes to business logic) told me, that because it's a new project, whenever I see a new solution, a better implementation of something, or something helpful to work with, I must not hesitate to tell him, and he will discuss it with the other leaders. So I told him about my approach and that I didn't understand the purpose of the old constructor code, and that nobody gave me a convincing explanation, he told me to look up by myself if there's something that backs up that approach given that I showed him resources that backup mine, in order to tell the orders in case mine is better, throwing away the other method.

So after all this story, my question is,

Does the javascript constructor approach have a name? I mean, Is it an actual standard, practice or recommendation? Because I could not find any information about it. It could be that I'm wrong and the constructor approach is better or valid, but because I have no info about it, I need to be sure in order to discuss my implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of interest, how come you don't do it the slightly simpler way of `(function($, etc) {...})(jQuerry, etc);`. Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Seems like they are making their own version of a constructor when javascript already has constructors built in. Seems like bad practice to me, certainly not best practice. See [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor) explanation of javascript constructors.

Comment: @DanielM I was going to answer your question but Jason Cust has already answered it for me.

Comment: JavaScript is very flexible and there are many ways to approach problem. This leads to holy wars that are nearly always a waste of time. I will say that your IIFE approach looks pretty pointless. I mean you're passing a function to a function just so that you can invoke it with a bunch of stuff that's global anyway. I get that you want local refs, but it's much simpler with a single IIFE like @DanielM said.

Comment: ...and Jason Cust didn't give an answer to that.

Comment: @AndrewMairose: It's really just the module pattern, but they're using an outer constructor to create the module instead of an IIFE with an object literal. Same outcome but probably a little better for debugging since the console will show some constructor data if the object itself is logged.

Comment: The Revealing Module pattern is basically what they're doing. https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/ If you're familiar with it already, then it probably just looks a little odd because they're using a constructor function. But as I noted above, this has benefits when debugging. It makes sense for a company to stick to a single, uniform pattern

Comment: Among other reasons for not assigning methods as a property of `this` directly in the object constructor (as with anything assigned as a property to `this`), doing so makes it enumerable by default. See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kuxuyataci/edit?js,console) for a basic example.

Comment: Either way they're enumerable by default but `Object.keys()` excludes inherited properties. `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Bar.prototype, "boo").enumerable; // true`  This is a valid point if we're not talking about a namespace object, but it seems pretty clear we are.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special meaning to the word `Constructor` in the JavaScript language; only what meanings your coworkers have been assigning to it. Some JS frameworks like dojo create similarly named functions, but they also have specialized, central ways of defining objects, and centralized places they call said constructor function (instead of manually calling it on the very next line, leaving room for errors)

It's also perhaps misleading to believe that any JavaScript objects must wait until the DOM is ready before constructing themselves. How do you think JQuery creates itself? (And it has to very early, before people write `$().ready` to make their onload function)

I don't know of any specific issue with the way that your coworkers are writing their objects, as long as they assign a very different semantic meaning to their current `Constructor` function. The code above such as `var _this = this` is the constructor. The contents of the was-Constructor function could best be described `onDOM` or similar. If they'd prefer to follow this system, it might be best if their class system was going through a central library; be it your own or someone else's.

Comment: using `.constructor` on an instance in js does give the function that created it (or `instance.constructor.name` for the string rep of the constructing functions name) so it isn't totally right to say `constructor` has no meaning in js expect any that's been defined by the developer. it does have inbuilt meaning

Comment: @atmd I'm perhaps a bit literal, but I was referring to `Constructor`.

Comment: *"The code above such as `var _this = this` is the constructor."* It isn't a constructor. It's an object that will hold the module's data. Or did I misunderstand what you're saying?

Comment: @squint Meant just what I said; **that code**, as in **that one line**, is the content of your "constructor function" (not `this` or `_this`, which is just a self-reference). JavaScript classes start as just their constructor function (`function MyClass(initParam) { this.initParam = initParam; }` and then often have prototype parameters and other functions attached to their created instances.

Comment: Then that's not correct. The content of the constructor function is more than just that one line, and `this` and `_this` are not self references to the constructor. They're references to a new object being created.

Comment: @squint Feel free to argue with yourself; no one has claimed `this` is the constructor, so it sounds like you just keep misreading something. But no matter which way you cut it, the block beginning with `function AccountingMovements { ` is a constructor. Take any further confusion you have to chat.

Comment: You just called it a self-reference. Sorry if I misunderstood, but the amount of misinformation on this page is staggering. This is a very simple concept and people seem to be trying so hard to confuse things. A "central library" isn't needed at all for this simple pattern. You don't want me to respond, then don't send me a notification.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference is the pollution of the global scope. Since they don't appear to be wrapping their functions in an IIFE, all of the functions and variables will be accessible from the global scope. This could could lead to bugs and security issues if 3rd party JS libs (or even some other internal code) reused any of those.

The approach you mentioned is a very useful pattern as it allows both for scoping your code and indicating which part needs to wait for the DOM:

```
// IIFE to create a closure to prevent global scope pollution
(function(code) {
  // execute `main` function with params
  code(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function main($, window, document) {
  $(function readyDOM() {
    //here goes the code when document is ready
  });

  // This is the rest of your code that is not dependent on the DOM
  // Such as any object (constructers) declarations
}));
```

However this is functionally equivalent to:

```
// IIFE to create a closure to prevent global scope pollution
(function main($, window, document) {
  $(function readyDOM() {
    //here goes the code when document is ready
  });

  // This is the rest of your code that is not dependent on the DOM
  // Such as any object (constructers) declarations
})(window.jQuery, window, document);
```

Either of these patterns can be used as a wrapper for their object declarations. So combining this with their object declaration:

```
// IIFE to create a closure to prevent global scope pollution
(function main($, window, document) {
  $(function readyDOM() {
    $AccountingMovements.Constructor();
  });

  // A better pattern for object constructors
  // Assigning properties directly to `this` in the object constructor
  //  makes them enumerable by default. See http://jsbin.com/kuxuyataci/edit?js,console
  function AccountingMovements() {
    //sometimes they use var _that = this;
    var _this = this;
  }
  AccountingMovements.prototype.Constructor = function Constructor() {
    //here goes the code when document is ready
  };

  // var will be hoisted
  var $AccountingMovements = new AccountingMovements();
})(window.jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: So there's no actual resource that backups the constructor approach, right?

Comment: This code is needlessly complex. There's just no reason shown to pass an anonymous function into an IIFE merely to invoke it immediately. This does the same thing: `(function($, window, document) { $(function() { /* DOM ready */ }); /* Immediate code */ })(window.jQuery, window, document);`

Comment: @squint Wooooo there. Speaking of "holy wars". :-P

Comment: @JasonCust: Just trying to beat down the misleading information on this page. I'm not engaging in holy wars by saying one approach is better than the other. Other people like you are making specious claims, like `var _that = this` is an anti-pattern. So if I do `var _that = {};` and put some properties on it with functions that may reference it,  and then return it, is that an anti-pattern too?

Comment: @jecarfor I don't recall anything supporting their claim. For a better understanding of object constructor patterns I would refer you to read [**You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes**](http://amzn.to/1CJRTcb) or at least Ch. 3: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md

Comment: @JasonCust , but what are the security issues of the constructor approach? (the one I posted)

Comment: @jecarfor It is entirely dependent on if those constructors are exposed to the global scope. If they are, say you have the Fort Knox of security on your servers but you use 3rd party JS libs from another CDN. If either they or someone else (through a man-in-the-middle attack for instance) is malicious and wants to, they could easily repurpose those constructors to suit their needs. Or more realistically create naming collisions which would lead to a lot of fun debugging it.

Comment: @squint I do not think I am making specious claims but as you say I am trying to shed light on what is generally misleading information. I would implore you to read at least the section on [**Lexical *this***](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#lexical-this) and see if you still think it is a specious claim.

Comment: I understand how `this` works in JS. What does the new ES6 function syntax and its lexically bound `this` have to do with the question? The fact is you're making assumptions about how the `_that` variable is used. It could very well be that the methods are going to be dependent on their own, dynamically assigned `this` value, making `.bind()` the wrong solution. It's a common pattern to invoke a function that creates an object and assign properties to it and return the object. The code above is doing exactly that, just using a constructor instead of an object literal with an IIFE.

Comment: @squint We are going to agree to disagree. I don't think you read the entire section (it uses the ES6 arrow function as an example leading to the point I am trying to show you) but it doesn't matter. Regarding your last point, if that is the case then there is no need to assign `this` as those methods should be assigned to the `prototype` and not within the function declaration. But again, lets just agree to disagree.

Comment: ...and there's no such thing as any kind of JS security on the client. If the JS is on the server, they're obviously not going to load 3rd party JS from a CDN. If they do, closures aren't going to help them.

Comment: @JasonCust: There's absolutely no reason to assign methods to the `.prototype` if the constructor is going to be used to create only a single instance, which seems to be the case here. Even with multiple instances, sometimes there are unique, local vars that they want functions to create. There's just not enough info to make any kind of real judgement here.

Comment: @jecarfor: Just be clear, there's *no such thing* as "secure" client side JavaScript. There are only some conveniences to help incompetent developers avoid overwriting stuff they shouldn't. If there's a man-in-the-middle attack, no JS pattern is going to help.

Comment: @jecarfor By *security* I mean expecting the code to behave as intended without someone purposely trying to change that. squint, you are an angry person and I like it. Hopefully you don't peruse the comments on YouTube for your own sake. :-P

Comment: Not angry at all, Jason. Just correcting your misunderstandings. I'm sorry that this upsets you. Fact is that there are many useful patterns.  Don't know why you want to hold such limiting views. Good programmers don't create narrow sets of rules. They understand their tools fully and use their knowledge accordingly.

Comment: @squint Agreed. Which is why shall agree to disagree. :D

Answer (score 0):

What they want to achieve with that it's an 'application bootstraper' or 'start button' and when the page is ready they call the `Constructor` but a more suitable name is `init` or `initialize` method.

In my opinion this is an absolutly crappy way for an application foundation/structure. This can be also used as a module starter etc.

Using `_this` as a reference to the main constructor/function/object is a good practice because soon you will get into closures and somehow you need to reference the main module.

`Constructor` I guess it's just a placeholder here, you should never name a variable like that. `AccountingMovementsConstructor` it's much better.

What you pasted here, isn't actually a pattern, just an initialize method inside a module.

Google for `Javascript design patterns` and read more about them.

And be aware, letting someone arhitect a large-scale javascript application with a Java or other different languages only experience: worst ideea ever.

As an alternative to the above code:

```
// Define your module

(function(w) {
    w.namespace.myModule = {
        init: function() {
            console.log('hey, Im ready to rock');
        },

        // Usually you have one of these also
        destroy: function() {
            console.log('good bye world...');
        }
    }
}(window));

// Fast alternative to $(document).ready(...)
$(function() {
    window.namespace.myModule.init(); // hey, Im ready to rock
});
```

You can include a `Factory function` to separate the public and private variables. But I'm not going into this right here, It's something you can do using Google :P

Comment: I agree with some of your points but not about using `_this` or similar. `var XXX = this` is for the most part an anti-pattern. It stems from a lack of understanding how `this` works in JS. Most solutions that use this pattern could use `bind` instead. For a deeper reason as to why I would recommend reading: [**You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures**](http://amzn.to/1GOabdN). Specifically the chapter on `this`: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/f07e52b93c688d9fdc9e579fdc2dafec5c9c5bbb/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md

Comment: And you are going to use `bind` of course but having a `this, self, that` variable is something else. Your answer is correct but not related to this question here. It comes handy when having inheritence and things get big :P they always do, what am I talking here :D

Answer (score 0):

#### You may have misunderstood each other.

The snippet you've given is, for the most part, **a JS way to declare a class**. Of course, for the sole purpose of executing a bunch of code on `ready` event this is overkill. But the project grows and you need to structure it. This is one of the many ways to do that, of which none is the best one. This one is familiar to programmers coming from pure-OOP languages like Java, that encourage (or even enforce) object-oriented architecture.

Since **JavaScript doesn't have class declaration syntax built-in** (implementations of < ES2015 don't at least), multiple approaches have emerged to do that. All I have seen involve declaration of a constructor function. Yours is not an exception: though I would say it's not ideal, constructor code is just fine in the constructor function itself that represents a class. I don't see why you would want to separate the construction process into two distinct steps: once the constructor has done its work the object should be ready for use, a separate construction step is unnecessary complication.

For instance, here's how [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) (roughly speaking, a syntactic layer on top of JS) does this:

```
# CoffeeScript
class Hi
  # A typical method
  # CS is indenetation-sensitive: class contents and
  # function implementations are indented one more level
  # -> denotes a function
  method: ->
    @a += 1

  # `constructor` is a special identifier in CS
  # code from that function goes into an unusual place
  constructor: ->
    @a = 5
```

Here's the output:

```
// Generated JavaScript
// Entire program is wrapped in IIFE, for isolation.
// Not relevant to the question, but since it's in the output
// I want to clarify why it's in there.
(function() {
  var Hi;

  Hi = (function() {
    Hi.prototype.method = function() {
      return this.a += 1;
    };

    function Hi() {
      this.a = 5;
    }

    return Hi;

  })();

}).call(this);
```